# setting ylim span_where python

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I want to use span_where like this:

```html
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as collections


t = np.arange(0.0, 2, 0.01)
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
s2 = 1.2*np.sin(4*np.pi*t)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('using span_where')
ax.plot(t, s1, color='black')
ax.axhline(0, color='black', lw=2)

collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
    t, ymin=0, ymax=1, where=s1 > 0, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(collection)

collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(
    t, ymin=-1, ymax=0, where=s1 < 0, facecolor='red', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_collection(collection)


plt.show()
```

but without knowing the ymin and ymax as they will change as my data changes. I'd like it to colour from the bottom to top of the yaxis, whatever it is. Best way to automate this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `ymin, ymax = ax.set_ylim()`? Or doesn't that work for you?

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't know how to do it for a subplot, but it works :-)